# Problem of graph with ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I don't understand why, but, with this code, I can't get a graph. Nothing is happening in output. And I have no errors.. Here is the code:

```
ListPlot[RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == (a[n] + b[n])/2, 
   b[n + 1] == (2 / (1 / a[n] + 1/b[n])), a[0] == 4, b[0] == 3}, {a, 
   b}, {n, 0, 30}],
 PlotRange -> {0, 100},
 ImageSize -> 400,
 AxesLabel -> {"n", "anbn"},
 PlotLabel -> "Premiers Termes :-) "
 ]
```

Do you know what is the problem?

Thanks for your time!!!

Edit: Now, changing a[0], b[0] and n, I have this:

[image]

New edit:

[image]

Comment: Exact calculations are too time consumption in this case. Is using a[0] == 4.0 and b[0] == 3.0 an option for you? I think you will have to do this numerically.

Comment: What do you mean? Its not an obligation to put a[0] and b[0] with these values. But, It must be superior to 0 for both, thats all .. Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: When you replace the 4 with 4.0 and the 3 with 3.0 you trigger numerical evaluation which is much faster. To see this, evaluate your RecurrenceTable (remove the plot stuff) replacing the 30 with much smaller values and increment them gradually. You will see some huge fractions that take increasingly more time to calculate.

Comment: Why is there only two points and not a wide range of points? is it not supposed to be points for a[0] a[1] ....... a[10] and same for b ? I put a new edit with your advices.

Comment: I dont understand why n dont have values higher than 3.55

Comment: Most of the point's seem to be coinciding, so you just don't see them. They're all there, though.

Comment: Is there any possibilities to differentiate a and b ?? For example, different colors? It looks like only (a_n) series is in the graph..

Comment: It's much easier to use `NestList[]`: `ListLinePlot[NestList[{Mean[#], HarmonicMean[#]} &, N[{4, 3}], 30]]`

Comment: Make sure that "Enable Dynamic Updating" is checking in the Evaluation menu.

Answer (score 1):

```
        I think you can see the dependence of a[0]=s, b[0]=q given below plot.

         Manipulate[
          ListLinePlot[
         RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == (a[n] + b[n])/2, 
       b[n + 1] == (2/((1/a[n]) + (1/b[n]))), a[0] == s, b[0] == q}, {a, 
      b}, {n, 0, 20, 1}], PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", Frame -> True, 
         PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 16}, PlotStyle -> Blue], {s, 1, 
      30}, {q, .001, 1}]
```

[image: plot of data]

Comment: Thanks !!! But we don't see b values, right?